# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: This domain is not hosted here

Tags: email, nopcommerce

I am performing some tests on my Nopcommerce site that should allow the user to type a message in to the contact box of the site and that message should be sent by email to a user.

When setting up and testing said user on the site, I am able to perform an email test against an internal email address and this works fine, I receive the email. However, if I try and send the email to an external email address, such as hotmail etc, I receive no error logs at all.

Has anyone ever come across this issue when trying to set up an email on a Nopcommerce site?

I am using port 25 however I have tried to use port 587 with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the username and password no longer existed for the server I was sending mail from. Moreover, another issue I had was that the mail still wasn't sending and was sitting in the Message queue. To overcome this I had to make sure that the bindings for the site on IIS were identical to the host values on the site. Doing this allowed me to send mail.